# Is Gauss law for gravity local?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, causality, locality

in Newtonian gravity, the gravitational field obeys the equation
$$\nabla^2 \phi = 4 \pi G \rho$$
David Tong in his notes on general relativity claims that this equation works well when $\rho$ is not a function of time, but when $\rho$ depends on time, then a change in $\rho$ would result in a change in $\phi$ throughout all of space. But this equation is a local equation, in the sense that I'm calculating the Laplacian of $\phi$ at the point $\vec{r}$ at the time $t$, and this is proportional to the density at the position $\vec{r}$ at the time $t$. So  how does a change in $\rho$ at one position affect the field at another position instantaneously according to this equation?

Comment: The solution to that differential equation can be written as an integral over space where $\phi$ at some point at time $t$ depends on $\rho$ at all points at that time $t$.  If you have studied electrostatics, that integral should be familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall, that given a point with mass $M$, its gravitational potential depending on the distance $r$ to the point is given by:
$$\phi(r)=-G\frac{M}{r}.$$
Recall as well, that given a continuum with density $\rho$, its gravitational potential at $\vec{r}$ is given by integrating over all the contributions:
$$\Phi(t,\vec{r})
=-G\int\mathrm d^3\vec{r}'\frac{\rho(t,\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}.$$
The problem here, is that when you move from the point $\vec{r}$ to the point $\vec{r}'$ to gather information about its contribution to the gravitational field (at $\vec{r}$!), you should also move into the past as the information took a time of $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|/c$ to travel from $\vec{r}'$ to $\vec{r}$. In the equation above, which can be transfered into your differential equation by applying the Laplace operator and using its fundamental solution:
$$-\Delta_{\vec{r}}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}=4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$$
**does not** consider that. Changing $\rho(t,\vec{r}')$ for any $\vec{r}'$ **does** affect $\Phi(t,\vec{r})$, even if $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$ are many light-years apart. The only thing that matters for this to work is the same time of $t$ on both sides. In the integral, every contribution from everywhere in space is regarded at this current time $t$, implying that the information travels with infinite speed. A better approach is therefore the following generalized integral using the speed of light $c$ with which the information about the gravitational field travels:
$$\Phi(t,\vec{r})
=G\int\mathrm d^3\vec{r}'\frac{\rho\left(t-\frac{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}{c},\vec{r}'\right)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|},$$
which can be transfered into a differential equation (the wave equation) by applying the D'Alembert operator (wave operator) and using its fundamental solution:
$$\square_{t,\vec{r}}\frac{\delta^1\left(t-t'-\frac{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}{c}\right)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}
=4\pi\delta^1(t-t')\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}').$$
The following wave equation now includes the effect of retardation (it is really called *retarded gravity*) and falls back to the Laplace equation either if $c\rightarrow\infty$ or if $\rho$ (and therefore $\Phi$) are independent of time like you mentioned, that David Tong claimed:
$$\square\Phi
=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Phi-\Delta\Phi
=-4\pi G\rho.$$
By the way, changing the sign in front of $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|/c$ from $-$ to $+$ changes the *retarded potential* into an *advanced potential* and instead of information from the past, information from the future enters your integral, which is why advanced potentials are rarely considered in physics. But they are: Retarded potentials describe the emission while advanced potentials describe the absorption of fields.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the value of the field in the neighbourhood of some point $\mathbf r_0$ is such that $\nabla^2\phi = 4\pi G \rho(\mathbf r_0)$

It happens for example outside a massive sphere, where $\rho = 0$, or inside a massive sphere with constant density. But it is not the case for a massive sphere with non constant density. For a point inside a hole from pole to pole across a sphere, with hole diameter much smaller than the sphere radius, $\nabla^2\phi \neq 0$, in spite of $\rho = 0$ locally.

In general, it is necessary to apply the Green function for this differential equation, which is an integral over all of space.

$$\phi(\mathbf{r}) = - \iiint  \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{ |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|}\, \mathrm{d}^3\! r'$$

Comment: Outside a massive sphere with constant density, isn't $\phi = GM/r$? The Laplacian of that at non zero r is zero.

Comment: Yes, in that case the differential equation is fulfilled locally as I said. $\rho = 0$ and the Laplacian is also zero.